# shutdown button disappears when logging in

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, settings, logout, package-management

recently installed the oneiric ocelot and its awesome,but one fine time i logged out of it and when i logged in the shutdown button disappears,when i upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 got a error message saying that the installation failed due to broken packages and when i restarted it worked.Gave this info so that it might give u guys a picture of what happened.had and issue after this with the software center and did't install google chrome from the deb file and had to manually install it from the terminal.had to run the code: `apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 libnspr4-0d
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcurl3 libnspr4-0d
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 247 kB of archives.
After this operation, 668 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe libnspr4-0d i386 4.8.7-0ubuntu3 [11.1 kB]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libcurl3 i386 7.21.6-3ubuntu3 [235 kB]
Fetched 247 kB in 2s (88.5 kB/s)  
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/perl: free(): invalid pointer: 0x097a9cac ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6ebc2)[0x17ebc2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6f862)[0x17f862]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x18294d]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_free_ent+0x64)[0x80cf934]
/usr/bin/perl[0x80cfcf4]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_undef+0x15d)[0x80d2fdd]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x5ac)[0x80e4a2c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x68c)[0x80e4b0c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_free_ent+0x12c)[0x80cf9fc]
/usr/bin/perl[0x80cfcf4]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_undef+0x15d)[0x80d2fdd]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x5ac)[0x80e4a2c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x68c)[0x80e4b0c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_free_ent+0x12c)[0x80cf9fc]
/usr/bin/perl[0x80cfcf4]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_undef+0x15d)[0x80d2fdd]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x5ac)[0x80e4a2c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x68c)[0x80e4b0c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_free_ent+0x12c)[0x80cf9fc]
/usr/bin/perl[0x80cfcf4]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_hv_undef+0x15d)[0x80d2fdd]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clear+0x5ac)[0x80e4a2c]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_free2+0x4b)[0x80e4e9b]
/usr/bin/perl[0x80e03e1]
/usr/bin/perl(Perl_sv_clean_objs+0x27)[0x80e08b7]
/usr/bin/perl(perl_destruct+0x1681)[0x8079331]
/usr/bin/perl(main+0xfb)[0x806145b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0x129113]
/usr/bin/perl[0x80614d1]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-00286000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675077    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00286000-00288000 r--p 00176000 08:01 3675077    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00288000-00289000 rw-p 00178000 08:01 3675077    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
00289000-0028c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0028c000-00290000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393617     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/IO/IO.so
00290000-00291000 r--p 00003000 08:01 393617     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/IO/IO.so
00291000-00292000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 393617     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/IO/IO.so
00292000-00295000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394356     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/CharWidth/CharWidth.so
00295000-00296000 r--p 00002000 08:01 394356     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/CharWidth/CharWidth.so
00296000-00297000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 394356     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/CharWidth/CharWidth.so
00297000-0029a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393634     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Hash/Util/Util.so
0029a000-0029b000 r--p 00002000 08:01 393634     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Hash/Util/Util.so
0029b000-0029c000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 393634     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Hash/Util/Util.so
002a7000-002ac000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394350     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Locale/gettext/gettext.so
002ac000-002ad000 r--p 00004000 08:01 394350     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Locale/gettext/gettext.so
002ad000-002ae000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 394350     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Locale/gettext/gettext.so
002ae000-002ca000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3670936    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
002ca000-002cb000 r--p 0001b000 08:01 3670936    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
002cb000-002cc000 rw-p 0001c000 08:01 3670936    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
002cd000-002f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675081    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
002f5000-002f6000 r--p 00028000 08:01 3675081    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
002f6000-002f7000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 3675081    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.13.so
002f7000-00347000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393621     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/re/re.so
00347000-00348000 r--p 0004f000 08:01 393621     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/re/re.so
00348000-00349000 rw-p 00050000 08:01 393621     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/re/re.so
004cd000-004e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675083    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
004e2000-004e3000 r--p 00015000 08:01 3675083    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
004e3000-004e4000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 3675083    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.13.so
004e4000-004e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00528000-0052d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 394358     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/Iconv/Iconv.so
0052d000-0052e000 r--p 00004000 08:01 394358     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/Iconv/Iconv.so
0052e000-0052f000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 394358     /usr/lib/perl5/auto/Text/Iconv/Iconv.so
006d6000-006df000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 396307     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Encode/Encode.so
006df000-006e0000 r--p 00008000 08:01 396307     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Encode/Encode.so
006e0000-006e1000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 396307     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Encode/Encode.so
007cc000-007d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675084    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
007d4000-007d5000 r--p 00007000 08:01 3675084    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
007d5000-007d6000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 3675084    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.13.so
0090f000-00917000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675079    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
00917000-00918000 r--p 00007000 08:01 3675079    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
00918000-00919000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 3675079    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.13.so
00919000-00940000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00c6a000-00c88000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675074    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00c88000-00c89000 r--p 0001d000 08:01 3675074    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00c89000-00c8a000 rw-p 0001e000 08:01 3675074    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
00d26000-00d2f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393616     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/List/Util/Util.so
00d2f000-00d30000 r--p 00008000 08:01 393616     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/List/Util/Util.so
00d30000-00d31000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 393616     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/List/Util/Util.so
00d51000-00d5c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675086    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
00d5c000-00d5d000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 3675086    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
00d5d000-00d5e000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 3675086    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.13.so
00da1000-00dba000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393629     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
00dba000-00dbc000 r--p 00018000 08:01 393629     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
00dbc000-00dbd000 rw-p 0001a000 08:01 393629     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
00e02000-00e0c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675088    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
00e0c000-00e0d000 r--p 00009000 08:01 3675088    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
00e0d000-00e0e000 rw-p 0000a000 08:01 3675088    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.13.so
00ed8000-00edb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675080    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
00edb000-00edc000 r--p 00002000 08:01 3675080    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
00edc000-00edd000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 3675080    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
00f00000-00f03000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 393618     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
00f03000-00f04000 r--p 00002000 08:01 393618     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
00f04000-00f05000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 393618     /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
00f2a000-00f41000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3675091    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00f41000-00f42000 r--p 00016000 08:01 3675091    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00f42000-00f43000 rw-p 00017000 08:01 3675091    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so
00f43000-00f45000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00f6f000-00f70000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
08048000-081a0000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 131240     /usr/bin/perl
081a0000-081a1000 r--p 00157000 08:01 131240     /usr/bin/perl
081a1000-081a3000 rw-p 00158000 08:01 131240     /usr/bin/perl
093ac000-0a565000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7300000-b7321000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7321000-b7400000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74dd000-b74de000 r--p 00859000 08:01 136189     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b74de000-b751e000 r--p 002bd000 08:01 136189     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b751e000-b771e000 r--p 00000000 08:01 136189     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
b771e000-b7720000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7730000-b7732000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bfd59000-bfd7a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Selecting previously deselected package libnspr4-0d.
(Reading database ... 156539 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libnspr4-0d (from .../libnspr4-0d_4.8.7-0ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libcurl3.
Unpacking libcurl3 (from .../libcurl3_7.21.6-3ubuntu3_i386.deb) ...
Setting up libnspr4-0d (4.8.7-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libcurl3 (7.21.6-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (14.0.835.163-r101024) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode.
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for menu ...
```

and after all this got the chrome installed along with some other software from the update manager

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is currently a bug in Oneiric that makes the right-most indicator crash when running apt-get or similar. It'll get fixed. In the meantime, you can press alt+f2 and run: killall unity-panel-service

This will restart the panel with all the indicators. If you want to track the bug, you can find it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/854292

Comment: k and i'm not able to understand the bug tracking ui in the link u posted but will definitely follow it and can u post a reply in case its released thx